# CSS - adding an additional div makes other elements jump to the left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to modify a solution to "sticky" elements for older browsers presented in [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/css-position-sticky-introduction-polyfills/).

Essentially it works by adding some javascript code to listen for scroll events. When one is detected, it puts `position: fixed` on the "sticky" to ensure it stays in place while the user scrolls. To prevent the element from jumping out of the page flow, it adds an identically sized div prior to the fixed element.

This is all fine, but I'm struggling to make the solution work on my page because I'm trying to fix a right-hand div inside a two-column layout. Even though it's setting the width to the same as the sticky, the menu jumps to the left when it "sticks".

The right-hand column is positioned with the following classes:

```
.objects {
    margin: 10px 30px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    top: 30px;
    width: 40%;
}

.objects .content-block {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

<div class="objects" id="sticky">
    <div class="content-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the javascript code is:

```
var menu = document.querySelector('#sticky');
var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect();
var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
placeholder.style.width = menuPosition.width + 'px';
var isAdded = false;

document.getElementById("content").addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (document.getElementById("content").scrollTop >= menuPosition.top && !isAdded) {

    menu.classList.add('sticky');
    menu.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder, menu);

    isAdded = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById("content").scrollTop < menuPosition.top && isAdded) {

    menu.classList.remove('sticky');
    menu.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);

    isAdded = false;
  }
});
```

It doesn't seem to make any difference what you set the width of the "placeholder" element to.

There's a [fiddle to show the issue here](https://jsfiddle.net/s9grgfhe/8/).

What do I need to change in my CSS to get the element to remain where it is in the right-hand column?

Comment: I don't normally ask this, but I would appreciate a clarification of the downvote, please? Is this not a clear problem statement, with example code?

Comment: the issue is the width ... initially ise 40% of parent container and when fixed it's 40% of viewport

Comment: @MattThrower Sorry. That was me by mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented above you need to adjust the width so it can work with static and fixed position the same (you can use `vw` unit). 40% may behave differently with both especially when the container of the element is not 100% width.

Then you should add `right:17px` (the width of the scroll). `right:17px` combined with `position:fixed` will have the same behavior as `float:right` in your case.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector('#sticky');
var menuPosition = menu.getBoundingClientRect();
var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
var isAdded = false;

document.getElementById("content").addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (document.getElementById("content").scrollTop >= menuPosition.top && !isAdded) {

    menu.classList.add('sticky');
    menu.parentNode.insertBefore(placeholder, menu);

    isAdded = true;
  } else if (document.getElementById("content").scrollTop < menuPosition.top && isAdded) {

    menu.classList.remove('sticky');
    menu.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);

    isAdded = false;
  }
});
```

```css
.drop-table {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45%;
}

.objects {
    margin: 10px 30px;
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    top: 30px;
    width: 40vw;
    right:17px;
}

.objects .content-block {
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}
        
#content {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 80px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: auto;
   z-index: 4;
}

 .sticky {
    top: 40px;
    position: fixed; 
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div>

        <div class="content-block drop-table">
        <ul>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li>AAA</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="objects" id="sticky">
            <div class="content-block">
                <div>
                    Assign
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getComputedStyle(menu).width` and `getComputedStyle(menu).height` will get you the actual dimensions of your sticky element. Make sure to add the `objects` class to your placeholder as well to position it at the same place as the original object.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the position: fixed property relies on you specifying element's position inside the containing block using top, right etc. Specyfing a "right" (f.e. right: 0) value together with "top" for .fixed should work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: I don't want to nitpick but, wouldn't it be better and more constructive (and also let users that give imprecise answers learn more and better themeselves) if when giving downvotes one explains why he's downvoting?

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes